# Unable to create table in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am running below simple query to create a simple table.

> create table test (id int, name varchar(20));

But I am getting the below error, please let know what need to be done exactly.

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from 
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:file:/user
>   /hive/warehouse/test is not a directory or unable to create one)

I have given full read/write access to /user/hive/warehouse folder.

Comment: I assume that it is just a display issue on SO, but check whether the actual error message also contains a space between /user and /hive/warehouse/test

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your hive user doesn't have permission for create director into hdfs. Whenever you create a table, hive will make a directory into  User/hive/warehouse/table but here It's not able to create a directory into user/hive/warehouse/ so give permission to this directory to allow your user to create a table.

http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/cdh/4-x/4-2-0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_18_7.html

Comment: and if already give permission so check the path you specify as hive.metastore.warehouse.dir in your hive-site.xml

Comment: Thanks. I'd appreciate if you could consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56121592/where-is-user-hive-warehouse-located  In my case, `/user/hive/warehouse/` doesn't exist, so I can't change its access mode. Where is it located?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a permissions issue. The change mode command below may help.

`hadoop fs -chmod -R 755 /user/hive/warehouse/`

Answer (score 1):

The error message says

```
file:/user /hive/warehouse/test".
```

Despite that space between the /user and the rest of the path, **file:/** means that Hive is trying to create that directory on your local file system instead on hdfs. There is probably problem with accessing configuration. I would check is HADOOP_CONF_DIR environment variable is properly initialized.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was exactly like yours(create internal table), not related to permission, but to storage, it was 100% used. Try checking for the same.