# How can I solve the error "file:/user/hive/warehouse/records is not a directory or unable to create one"?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

```
hive> CREATE TABLE records (year STRING, temperature INT, quality INT)
    > ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    >   FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:file:/user/hive/warehouse/records is not a directory or unable to create one)
```

How can I solve the error?

where is `/user/hive/warehouse/` located? In my local ext4 filesystems under Ubuntu, there is no `/user/hive/warehouse/` such a path.

How can I get information about i.e. examine `/user/hive/warehouse/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create **/user/hive/warehouse** folder in hdfs file system before running hive commands.

Hive internally uses hadoop hdfs file system to store database data. You can check the hdfs directory path in hive-default.xml and/or hive-site.xml configuration file or in hive terminal, using below command

```
hive> set hive.metastore.warehouse.dir;
```

As mentioned Hive uses Hadoop, so

- Hadoop must be installed and running status
- HADOOP_HOME environment variable must be set

  `export HADOOP_HOME=hadoop-install-dir`

  `export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin`
- Directories in hdfs file system must be created and given access to hive

  `hadoop fs -mkdir -p /tmp`

  `hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/hive/warehouse`

  `hadoop fs -chmod g+w /tmp`

  `hadoop fs -chmod g+w /user/hive/warehouse`

To list directories in hdfs file system

```
hadoop fs -ls /user
hadoop fs -ls /
hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/
```

[Hive Wiki page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#GettingStarted-RunningHive)